# File is not found when executing test with maven clean test

Tags: java, spring, maven

In my maven java project, I have a directory with files:

`src/test/resources/data/files/test.txt`

this is a test file under test resources.

I have a class that looks for the file if it is available:

```
public class MyPoller{

    private boolean isFileAvailable(String file) {
        try {
            ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(file);
            boolean exists = Files.exists(Paths.get(classPathResource.getFile().getPath()));
            if (exists) {
                FileTime modFileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(Paths.get(classPathResource.getFile().getPath()));
                long modFileMinutes = modFileTime.to(TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                long minutes = FileTime.from(Instant.now()).to(TimeUnit.MINUTES);

                return minutes - modFileMinutes >= 5;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to check file is available", e);
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

It uses `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;`

From my cucumber tests (feature files) I pass the file path to `isFileAvailable()` as `data\files\test.txt` and the file is found and returns true and the test is successful.

However, when I execute `mvn clean test`, the condition in the method is failing and my build is not successful. I am not sure what the issue is and if I have missed something.

Comment: Can you run "mvn -x clean test" and share the results

Comment: Most likely is because you are using a relative route and mvn is executed from a diferent pathr. Try to use absolute route

Comment: seems it is the condition. file is found but the condition is failing